# Setup ReactJS environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am new on `ReactJS` and learning from scratch. I see some using **babel** and some are **webpack** to configure as well some use **yarn package manager**. So can you suggest me which is better to work with react.

I just curious about configuring reactJS environment thorugh which bundle or package manager?

Comment: This might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-vLtsKvp_4 (uses npm, babel, webpack)

Comment: You can study from http://mern.io/

Comment: @AlexNguyen. I think its about mean stack development. There is redux but is it same as react?

Comment: @MehulMohan.. Ok i will see mate. Thanks

Comment: Redux is a state management library.

Comment: @CodinCat.. Yes mate. You are right

Comment: @Kumar if you do not want to use redux you can exclude it and then your reactjs dev environment is all ready.

Comment: @AlexNguyen.. Thanks a lot for suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

babel is a transpiler, webpack is a bundler and yarn (or npm) is a package manager. These tools are for different purposes. And usually we use *all* of them together.

React has a very handy tool called [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). With this tool you don't need to configure babel and webpack by yourself so you can start to learn React easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is best place to start up with ReactJS

> In older versions you need to setup react with babel and webpack but now on current latest version you can directly start with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

[ReactJS Installation and startup guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/try-react.html)

Just follows steps on this page, then run HelloWorld example which is best programs to start with any new programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can start working with react using [create react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)(along with official [react documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/)) which will provide you app structure with no build configuration. So there is no need to worry about babel, webpack. you will get all configured with proper documentation. It's up to you to use yarn or npm as package manager.